# http request in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Iam using following code to send request to a host machine

is there any possible way to send a `json` data along with `options.`

```
 var options = {
            host: '172.16.2.51',
            port: 9090,
            path: '/start',
            method: 'POST'
        };
        var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
            res.on('data', function (d) {               
                console.log(d.toString());
            });
        });
        req.on('error', function (e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
        req.end();
```

code in host machine.Here how can i get the json data.

```
    var sever = http.createserver(function(req,res){
    switch(req.url){

    case:'/start':

         req.on('data',function(chuck){});
    req.on('end',function(){

    });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send data you need use [req.write](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)

For example;

```
req.write(JSON.stringify({'test': 1});
req.end();
```

But as Andrew suggested in his answer you can use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to help ease HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to do the "post" work.

And on the "host machine", use [express](http://expressjs.com/).